# iphone - Tinting/shading/glowing an animated UIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, animation, uiimage

I'm currently using `[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"..." duration:1.0f]` to animate a series of PNG images in my iOS 7 app.

When the image is still, I use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` as follows:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale); 
    {
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
        [color setFill];
        [path fillWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceAtop alpha:1.0];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    } UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

...and then CAAnimation to glow/tint/shade the image mask. For the animated image, though, is there a way to animate the mask so that it follows the animated PNG? (By "mask" I mean shape or silhouette of the image content that I'm animating.)